# Limit number of records in outer join based on left-hand table

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables that I am outer joining together: "Post" left outer join with "Comments".

There is a one-to-many relationship between Post and Comments.

I would like to be able to pull the first, say 10, Post records and all of the associated Comments (if any) for each Post.

The way I would usually do this would be to have a Common Table Expression and use ROW_NUMBER() OVER. However, ROW_NUMBER() counts each row, which in this case would not work since I only want to count the Post records.

I was looking at ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION), but it does not work how I would expect it.

So if want the first 5 Posts, I would get something like:

```
PostNumber     PostId     CommentId
1              1          1
1              1          2
2              2          -
3              8          3
3              8          4
4              9          5
5              15         -
```

Comment: You want ten POSTS records, with COMMENTS where there could be 1+?  So if POSTS record #1 has 100+ comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at using [DENSE_RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) function

> Returns the rank of rows within the
>   partition of a result set, without any
>   gaps in the ranking. The rank of a row
>   is one plus the number of distinct
>   ranks that come before the row in
>   question.

Something like

```
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  p.*,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY p.PostID) DenseRankID
        FROM    Post p LEFT JOIN
                Comments c ON p.PostID = c.PostID
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Vals 
WHERE   DenseRankID <= 10
```